# Flutter pub get info about a package from command line

Tags: flutter, version, dart-pub

I need to get the latest version(just number, not a package) of a certain package hosted on pub.dev from the command line.

Something like `npm view url-loader version` from npm.
Can not find any analogues so far.

I'm creating a script that automatically changes the version in pubspec.yaml to the latest+1 and publishes the package. The only option i have found so far is to download the html contents of the package web page on pub.dev and search for the version there which does not seem to be very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply let the version in `pubspec.yml` blank. like:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons:
```